# Disable migrations for django.contrib.auth application

Tags: django

I replaced in my project django.contrib.auth application with custom application and authentication backend, but still use some functions/classes from original app(like _user_has_perm, _user_has_module_perms, etc).

The problem is if I don't put  django.contrib.auth in INSTALLED_APPS i get this warning: 

`RemovedInDjango19Warning: Model class django.contrib.auth.models.User doesn't declare an explicit app_label and either isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS or else was imported before its application was loaded. This will no longer be supported in Django 1.9.`

But if I put it in INSTALLED_APPS, on next migrate are created tables which I replaced with my custom models.

So, how can I disable migration for django.contrib.auth ?

Comment: Do you want to prevent just the User table, or all tables from being created?

Comment: I want to prevent creation of tables auth_group, auth_permission, auth_group_permissions and  django_content_type. auth_user table is not created..

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a custom User model, you need to specify it in `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`; this will prevent Django from loading the default model.

Comment: I did this. My custom app is named `cauth`. In settings.py I have this line: `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'cauth.User'`. This are my imports `from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
auth.get_backends
from django.contrib.auth.models import (_user_has_perm, _user_has_module_perms,
                                        _user_get_all_permissions)
from django.contrib.auth import logout as django_logout
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
`